# web3 unlock account error

Tags: go-ethereum

I have two geth nodes, each has an account:

```
node1(IP:192.168.43.12): account1
node2(IP:192.168.43.39): account2
```

the two accounts are created using `geth --datadir /root/chain/node1/data account new`, the keystore files are generated and saved on each node.

I use web3 to attach **node1** in nodejs environment:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3('http://192.168.43.12:8545');
```

and try to unlock **account2 created on node2** before sending a token transaction like below:

```
await web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(account2, "account2 password", 1000);
```

I got an error like below:

```
Error: Node error: {"code":-32000,"message":"no key for given address or file"}
```

I also tried if attach to node2 and the unlock process is correct.

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3('http://192.168.43.39:8545');
await web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(account2, "account2 password", 1000);
```

How can I unlock an account use web3 without the limitation of node connection?

Thanks.

Comment: did you test your code locally with ganache and checked if its working? since from the code posted i can see you are using a node on a remote server.

Comment: the code can work as I said in the post. the problem is how to unlock any account created in node1 when attaching node2 using web3 lib. If I have already known the private key, how  to make web3 object aware of it. In this way, I should not need to call "we3.eth.personal.unlockAccount()"?

Comment: I want to unlock an account created on remote node. the account's keystore file is also saved in that node.

Comment: you will need to connect to that node directly by setting the web3 provider and then unlock your account.

Answer (score 0):

The account files are located in /root/chain/node1/data/keystore folder (in your case), so you need to copy both keys to both nodes, because the accounts are local per node

Comment: Can I specify the path of keystore file when unlock account using web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(account, "account password", unlocktime)? if possible, then I can put keystore file on other computer instead of /root/chain/node1/data/keystore folder

Comment: The key files are local per node, so you just need to copy the files from the other comuter